# Obtaining all possible ways to concatenate matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, combinatorics, concatenation

With `Prepend` we can add a line to all matrices in a set, like this:

```
X = {{{1,3,7,6},{2,1,3,2},{3,1,7,2}},{{7,7,1,8},{9,3,4,2},{2,4,4,6}},{{1,6,7,1},{4,5,8,1},{5,5,7,3}}};
Map[Prepend[{1, 1, 1, 1}]]@X
```

This code adds the line `{1,1,1,1}` to each matrix of the set `X`.

To concatenate a given matrix `2 x 4` with each matrix of the set `X` we can use `Prepend` twice. But if

```
Y={{{2,6,8,2},{9,4,9,8}},{{1,7,4,2},{7,6,9,6}}}
```

how can I obtain all the possible concatenations of the matrices from `Y` with those from `X` (in this order)?

The order is important. Each element of the resultant set is a matrix whose first two lines are a matrix from `Y` and the last ones is a matrix from `X`, like this one:

```
{{2,6,8,2},{9,4,9,8},{1,3,7,6},{2,1,3,2},{3,1,7,2}}
```

The code have to work on `n x 9` matrices (`n < 5`).

Comment: You have an extra `1` in the last row of the second matrix of `X`. You are also missing a comma in the first row of the second matrix of `Y`.

Comment: @Edmund Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Join @@@ Tuples[{Y, X}]
```

> ```
> {{{2, 6, 8, 2}, {9, 4, 9, 8}, {1, 3, 7, 6}, {2, 1, 3, 2}, {3, 1, 7, 2}},
>  {{2, 6, 8, 2}, {9, 4, 9, 8}, {7, 7, 1, 8}, {9, 3, 4, 2}, {2, 4, 4, 6}},
>  {{2, 6, 8, 2}, {9, 4, 9, 8}, {1, 6, 7, 1}, {4, 5, 8, 1}, {5, 5, 7, 3}},
>  {{1, 7, 4, 2}, {7, 6, 9, 6}, {1, 3, 7, 6}, {2, 1, 3, 2}, {3, 1, 7, 2}},
>  {{1, 7, 4, 2}, {7, 6, 9, 6}, {7, 7, 1, 8}, {9, 3, 4, 2}, {2, 4, 4, 6}},
>  {{1, 7, 4, 2}, {7, 6, 9, 6}, {1, 6, 7, 1}, {4, 5, 8, 1}, {5, 5, 7, 3}}}
> ```

Comment: You stalker! :-) Second time in one day.

Comment: Indeed, you are a wizard.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`Outer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html) with [`ArrayFlatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html).

```
res = Flatten[Outer[ArrayFlatten[{{#1}, {#2}}] &, y, x, 1], 1];
MatrixForm /@ res
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Edmund. =D